# PHP get_result() causing Page cannot be displayed

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is my code:

```
/* database connection tested and working*/

if (!($sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?"))) 
{
    echo "Prepare failed";
}

if (!$sql->bind_param("i", `ryan`)) 
{
    echo "Binding parameters failed";
}

if (!$sql->execute()) 
{
    echo "Execute failed";
}
```

Up to this point, everything works fine, no errors display, and I can `print_r` the `$sql` array.

As soon as I add this code:

```
$result = $sql->get_result();
```

I get an error saying that "The website cannot display the page". I remove it, it works fine.

PS: This is a print out of `$sql`

```
mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => -1 [insert_id] => 0 [num_rows] => 0 [param_count] => 1 [field_count] => 1 [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [sqlstate] => 00000 [id] => 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these lines of code for error reporting.  You may get a better description of the problem.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function **get_result** is only available if you have MySQLnd installed.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Answer (score 0):

First thing:

```
if (!$sql->bind_param("i", `ryan`)) 
{
    echo "Binding parameters failed";
}
```

which should be:

```
if (!$sql->bind_param("s", 'ryan')) 
{
    echo "Binding parameters failed";
}
```

You had backtics ``` `` ``` wrapping `ryan` and `i` which is for integer not string.

```
-i  corresponding variable has type integer

-d  corresponding variable has type double

-s  corresponding variable has type string

-b  corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
```